# libpng error in appcelerator android app packaging

Tags: android, appcelerator

I am getting this error while packaging my app:

```
*[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable/appicon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable/background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-notlong-port-ldpi/background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-long-port-ldpi/background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
 /** Error repeats for all pngs in directory (Trunked the log)
/Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-long-port-hdpi/background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-notlong-land-hdpi/background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
[ERROR] :  libpng error: Read Error
[ERROR] :  ERROR: Failure processing PNG image /Users/rajeshkumar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/2Knocks/build/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/rajeshkumar/.appcelerator/install/4.1.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1*
```

Please provide solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem some days back to resolve this issue. it's resolved now
first of all make sure following things are perfect.

1. android build tools should be latest (Currently i'm using version 22.0.1)
2. include required theme files in project that is specified in tiapp.xml(if you have already this files in place try to update android SDK)

Comment: Thanks I will try you solutions

Comment: I have replaced Titanium SDK, restarted Titanium Studio and issue resolved. Hope it will help others .